# Launcher Activity is opening twice in my new SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, adt, android-sdk-2.3

I am recently facing a problem while creating new android application in both eclipse as well as android studio.
I am using same SDK in both eclipse and android studio.

When I create a new application and i simply run it. The launcher activity was getting loaded twice.
Means, I am getting MainActivity loading twice one on top of another. 
OnCreate() method of my MainActivity also got invoked twice.

The code goes like follows

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.sample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    System.out.println("OnCreate Invoked");
}
}
```

Output

```
OnCreate Invoked
OnCreate Invoked
```

Can you please help me in resolving this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code here so people can help you to sort out your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Pratt posted

Comment: Are you calling MainActivity from somewhere else or its only called as a Launcher?

Comment: And this is when you are not rotating the device at all and is kept in one orientation ?

Comment: No Prett, I am not calling MainActivity from anywhere apart from Launcher.

Comment: Shobhit Puri, I am getting "Oncreate Invoked" printed twice without changing the device orientation.

Comment: And to which version of Android does `22` corresponds to in your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: 22 corresponds to Android L preview Luksprog. I have recently updated the SDK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems you are getting multiple instance of your first activity.

Use this in manifest of 1st activity:

android:launchMode="singleTop"

Answer (score -1):

If I set orientation programatically in onCreate - I can reproduce this issue.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

If needed, set activity orientation in the manifest file like this.

```
       <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```